# Can't query datetime column in SQLAlchemy with postgreSQL

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, datetime, sqlalchemy

I want to delete rows based on a datetime filter.

I created a table with DateTime column without timezone using similar script.

```py
class VolumeInfo(Base):
    ...
    date: datetime.datetime = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
```

Then I try to delete rows using such filter

```py
days_interval = 10
to_date = datetime.datetime.combine(
            datetime.datetime.utcnow().date(),
            datetime.time(0, 0, 0, 0),
        ).replace(tzinfo=None)
from_date = to_date - datetime.timedelta(days=days_interval)

query = delete(VolumeInfo).where(Volume.date < from_date)
```

Unexpectedly, sometimes there is no error, but sometimes there is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "script.py", line 381, in delete_volumes
    db.execute(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1660, in execute
    ) = compile_state_cls.orm_pre_session_exec(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1843, in orm_pre_session_exec
    update_options = cls._do_pre_synchronize_evaluate(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 2007, in _do_pre_synchronize_evaluate
    matched_objects = [
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 2012, in <listcomp>
    and eval_condition(state.obj())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/evaluator.py", line 211, in evaluate
    return operator(eval_left(obj), eval_right(obj))
TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
```

Using python3.10 in docker (image python:3.10-slim) and postgreSQL database with psycopg2 driver.
I have already tried all possible options, but this error appears every once in a while

How can i solve this? or where I made a mistake?

UPD1:
[image: error description]

Comment: I'm going to say `Volume.date` has a time zone offset. Look at the data type for the field in the database and/or select it in a SQLAlchemy query and see what is returned.

Comment: They both have no timezome offset. I've installed [better-exceptions](https://github.com/Qix-/better-exceptions) to see what is the obj. I updated question with information about obj

Comment: The obj information is not really useful as it does not show the content of the VolumeInfo object. Start from the position that the error , 'TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes' is correct and work from there. I would start by just selecting `Volume.date` by itself in a query and seeing what it returns?

Comment: Execute the script `q = select(VolumeInfo).limit(1)
    a = db.execute(q).scalar()
    print(a)` which returns `<VolumeInfo for contract: 46 date: 09-01-2023 volume: 0.0>` date=datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 9, 0, 0) without timezone

Comment: Hmm, the only thing I can think of at this point is to look at the Postgres log and see what is hitting the database.

Comment: What is the data type for `VolumeInfo.date` in the database?

Comment: Simple timestamp (without timezone). Its also strange, that you can use both datetime and datetime with timezone to filter rows using sqlalchemy without any errors on a column with default timestamp type.

Comment: Still saying the error is correct. That means either: 1) The error is coming from some other piece of code or 2) At some point in the process one of the datetimes is gaining an offset.  This is going  to mean a step by step analysis of the process and well as monitoring the Postgres log.